# How to create a jar (SDK) in AOSP?

Tags: android, sdk, android-source

I have added a new hardware to my platform.

How can I create an SDK to provide some interface for developers?

I don't need the whole Android SDK like Google provides. It's just about my hardware - as Samsung provides gesture SDK, fingerprint SDK etc. So one can use this special SDK when you develop an app for a  Samsung phone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What You're aiming is SDK Add-on which as the name says is addition to to current SDK.
To generate one from the AOSP write this in the command line:

```
source build/envsetup.sh
lunch sdk-eng
make PRODUCT-add_on_name-sdk_addon
```

For a robust guide including how to implement the new add-on look [here](http://elinux.org/images/5/5c/Build_and_Distributing_SDK_Add-Ons.pdf).

Comment: How to build sdk_addon for windows ?

Comment: @RanjithKP It look like that Window platform is not supported, Here is link for more details.

Link: https://source.android.com/setup/build/requirements#os